# Как преобразовать ссылку Яндекс карты в координаты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Сейчас Яндекс Карты дают возможность поделиться картой или местом через "Меню - Поделиться"

Ссылка имеет вид: https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCQtjTBt1A

Есть ли возможность преобразовать эту ссылку в координаты с использованием Yanex.MAP API JS?

При переходе по ссылке происходит редирект на другую ссылку, уже содержащую координаты, которые мне нужны.

Comment: А почему вы просто не можете скопировать развернутый адрес в строке браузера?

Comment: Такая логика кейса. Юзер вставляет ссылку, и у него отображается карта.

Comment: Развернуть ссылку через API нельзя, это внутренняя логика Яндекса. Но этот же хвост короткой ссылки можно самому подставлять в код виджета с картой и показывать его пользователю.

Comment: Спасибо, остается только так.

Comment: Извини, не совсем понял. Можешь поподробнее описать, что ты имеешь ввиду под "подставлять в код виджета"?

Comment: Основная часть кода виджета выглядит так: <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCQtjTBt1A" width="560" height="400"></iframe> Если вы будете подставлять указанный выше "хвост" вместо хвоста УРЛа элемента <iframe src>, то будете получать рабочий виджет для скопированной ссылки пользователя.

Comment: Вон оно что, я использую компонент Vue.js <vue-yandex-maps>, но мысль я понял. Благодарю.